# Babelfor doesn't obfuscate well winform "fieldName"?

Tags: .net, devexpress, obfuscation

I've a winform control(a grid) from devexpress. It has some columns, and for each column, we have a "FieldName", which reference the property of the bound class.

The bound class is a private class of the user control. 
Currently, this column works in debug/release, but once we obfuscate it, it isn't bound anymore.

Is this something supported by BabelFor? Or do I need to exclude this from the serialization?

Answer (score 0):

The FieldName/DataMember (e.g. [column.FieldName](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.FieldName.property)) value is used as a unique identifier of the specific data property. The simplest way to keep the value and name synchronous is using the `nameof()` feature:

```
columnForDataProperty.FieldName = nameof(DataObject.DataProperty);
...
editorForDataProperty.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", dataSource: dataObjectBindingSource, dataMember: nameof(DataObject.DataProperty));
```

> You can use the feature above **when** you are using bindings created at runtime and **if** the BabelFor.Net tool correctly proceeds with the `nameof()` language feature.

If you are used data-bindings configured in design mode you should either remove the specific data property from obfuscation or change the FieldName/DataMember value accordingly.

In both cases please contact the [BabelFor.Net support](http://support@babelfor.net) to for more details on BabelFor supported features and configuration specifics.

Comment: Yeah I see, But I don't trust us to always go through the Designer.cs ^^. Any idea how this could have worked before on `Dotfuscator` ?